# How to use SAS code to make a table like this?

Tags: arrays, sas

I am new to SAS programming and have tried a lot of times try to convert the table on the left to the right one use sas code....Could anyone help me?

This is the source table. If today is Monday, then the code will run to convert the source table into the output table.The blank of the output table is the No. of student registered that week. The week starts from Sunday.

[image: Source Table]

[image: Output Table]

Answer (score 0):

You can enter data into SAS like this

```
DATA REGISTRATION;
INPUT Height Weight Name $ Sex $ Date date9. School $;
FORMAT Date date9.;
CARDS;
    158 50 Jane F 9-Sep-14 Law
    169 43 Jannie F 6-Aug-14 IT
RUN;
```

I think your question about transforming the data has been already answered in the linked post. Let us know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Hi Kostya, thank you so much. Actually, what I wanna ask is more than the question I posted there..But I am afraid of troubling others too much, thus only posted like that.If you have time, do you mind me emailing you my complete question, coz I do not have enough reputation to post images here...Thank you.